# Добавление дополнительных файлов pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

Возникла необходимость собрать проект на Python в один exe-файл. Воспользовался pyinstaller. Собрал все командой `pyinstaller main.py`. Далее подключаю gif-изображение с помощью

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'maze_game/grass2.gif:.' maze_game/main_menu.py
```

Получаю ошибку `pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: "'maze_game/grass2.gif:.'"` Эта ошибка также появляется, когда добавляю и файлы с расширением .txt.

Как исправить ошибку? Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Как вариант, попробуйте с двойными кавычками вместо одинарных (или вообще без них). + Для бинарных данных (которыми являются файлы изображений) используйте `--add-binary` вместо `--add-data`.

Comment: спасибо большое